# Problems with misaligned excel table in sg.Output

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formatting, pysimplegui

How could I correctly format the output of some excel columns (previously imported from a file (pd.read_excel)) to an output using sg.Output?

importing the file:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/file.xlsx', usecols="A,B,C")
```

the output in sg.output:

```
layout = [[sg.Text('Error Log', size=(43, 1), justification='center', text_color='#00226F',

         font=("Helvetica", 19), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE)],

   [sg.Column(colum1), sg.Column(colum2)] ,

[sg.Frame('Error Code: [ XXXX ] ', 

    [[sg.Input(size=(31, 1),  enable_events=True)],

    [sg.Button('Display Error Code'),sg.Button("Sensor and Actuator Layout")],

[sg.Output(size=(81, 12), key='-OUTPUT-')]], title_color='#00226F')],[sg.Button('Submit', visible=False, bind_return_key=True)]]
```

and printing:

```
 print(df[df["CODE :"] == values[0] ].head())
```

I can't get the columns to align correctly:

[misaligned excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJyAl.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There're two issues here

- `sg.Output` show the text, no format function provided. So you have to get the right style of text before print it to `sg.Output`. Call method `to_string(index=False, justify='left')` of DataFrame to remove index and left justified.
- To be well aligned by character, you should use monospace font for `sg.Output`, like `font=("Courier New", 11)`.

Example Code (With index, the format maybe not go well)

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = {
    "CODE :": ['1005'],
    "ERROR :": ['DMA5(Lift Down) malfunction'],
    "ACTION :": ['Replace the motor'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Error Code: [ XXXX ]"),
     sg.Input(size=(31, 1), key='-INPUT-')],
    [sg.Output(size=(81, 12), font=('Courier New', 11), key='-OUTPUT-')],
    [sg.Button('Submit', visible=False, bind_return_key=True)],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        text = df[df["CODE :"] == values['-INPUT-']].head().to_string(index=False, justify='left')
        print(text)

window.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it has solved part of the problem, If I do not find another solution, it could be better for me, the index was hidden and the columns were adjusted a bit, although not quite well.

Comment: Part of the problem ? any issue still there ?

Comment: No, the problem was solved